# When i set the GPIO pin as output in my python cgi script, after that line my browser does not execute the cgi script. Why?

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
print "<h1> line 4 </h1>"
```

The above does not print line 4 in client's browser

Comment: All the python GPIO statements are in seperate lines

Comment: What makes you think that the script is being executed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which webserver you are using, but in general they don't run CGI scripts with root privileges, meaning the script will fail when it tries to access the GPIOs.

You could check the server error logs to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

I've placed the following script in /usr/lib/cgi-bin with the name joan.html (made executable with chmod +x) on a Pi2 called paul.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio

print"""
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
   <title>pigpio cgi</title>
</head>
<body>
"""

pi=pigpio.pi()
pi.set_PWM_frequency(4, 0)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(4,128)
print("<h2>gpio 4 frequency={}</h2>".format(pi.get_PWM_frequency(4)))
pi.stop()

print"""
</body>
</html>
"""
```

I'm using apache2 on the Pi with cgi enabled with the command

```
sudo a2enmod cgid
```

The pigpio daemon has been started on the pi with the command

```
sudo pigpiod
```

Entering the following command on a networked browser runs the script.

```
http://paul/cgi-bin/joan.html
```